# Regex String with optional parts

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have this two example string, and I am building a regex for cover both

```
[[CONTENT:Image|||23123123123|||urlClipping|||true]]
[[CONTENT:Image|||23123123123|||urlClipping]]
```

I'm need to separate the inner params from the separators (|||) and the beginning and end ([[,]])

So far I've tried with

```
\[{2}CONTENT:([^\|]*)\|{3}([^\]]*)\|{3}([^\]]*)(\|{3}([^\]]*))?\]{2}
```

And

```
\[{2}CONTENT:([^\|]*)\|{3}([^\]]*)\|{3}([^\]]*)(?:\|{3}([^\]]*))?\]{2}
```

But both o them merges two params into one

How can I fix this regex?

Comment: `[\]]*` is greedy, use `*?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is! Wow you're so fast. Thank you very much!